# Why Images are rotated 90 degree in ImageView?

Tags: android

Why images are rotated 90 degree in imageView?? and how to fix it??

All images in gallery are not rotated 90 degree in imageView.

I don't know why some images are rotated 90 degree in imageView.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data){
    if(requestCode == 100){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            try{
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView)View.inflate(this, R.layout.imagelayout, null);
                Uri imgUri = data.getData();

             Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imgUri);
                int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                int newHeight = height;
                int newWidth = width;
                float rate = 0.0f;

                if(width > height ){
                    if(imageFlipper.getWidth() < width ){
                        rate = imageFlipper.getWidth() / (float) width ;
                        newHeight = (int) (height * rate);
                        newWidth = imageFlipper.getWidth();
                    }
                }else{
                    if(imageFlipper.getHeight() < height ){
                        rate = imageFlipper.getHeight() / (float) height ;
                        newWidth = (int) (width * rate);
                        newHeight = imageFlipper.getHeight();
                    }
                }


              Bitmap reSize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap , newWidth , newHeight,true);

              imageView.setImageBitmap(reSize);

              //imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
                imageFlipper.addView(imageView);
                imageFlipper.setDisplayedChild(imageFlipper.getChildCount() - 1);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this happen even without imageFlipper ?

Comment: oh, i will try `~~

Answer (score 3):

In some devices, when the camera is launched the orientation would change. In one of my apps, I also faced this issue. To handle this we need to find the orientation and rotate the picture accordingly.

```
// capture image orientation

    public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Context context, Uri imageUri,
            String imagePath) {
        int rotate = 0;
        try {
            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
            File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            }

            Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
            Log.i("RotateImage", "Rotate value: " + rotate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rotate;
    }
```

We need to use this integer returned to set the angle for Imageview.

```
int rotateImage = getCameraPhotoOrientation(this, uriLargeImage,
                    mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());

articleview.setRotation(rotateImage); // articleview is ImageView
```

So basically, please find the orientation of the photo as and when it is taken. This is in ExifInterface. Use this information to rotate.

Hope this helps. All the best.

Comment: Thanks  your comment. I have questions regarding this issue.

Comment: please let me know what questions you have, hope you tried the code change suggested

Comment: if image is rotated 90 degree to the right.  To correct orientation of photo , image is rotated 90 degree to the left?  left direction option is -(minus) ??

Comment: Don't worry about that. Once you provide the complete path of the imageFile, the Exif information will be obtained from it and the angle to be rotated will be matched and returned accordingly. You just need to get back the integer value and assign it as shown. More on Exif at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

Answer (score 1):

You must set the rotation in the imageview with which the photo was taken:

```
 imageView.setRotation(getCameraPhotoOrientation(filepath));
 imageView.setImageURI( Uri.fromFile(filepath));



 public static int getCameraPhotoOrientation(String imagePath) {
    int rotate = 0;
    try {
        ExifInterface exif  = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        switch (orientation) {

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            default:
                rotate = 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rotate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before it does it automatically. The way I fixed this, was by using this ImageCropper, which counter-rotates it automatically, which is amazing.

Click here: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

So not only do you get to crop and rotate your image, but it fixes the problem too!!

Answer (score 0):

/**
* Rotate a bitmap clockwise and anticlockwise
*/

```
    btn_clock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clockWise);
    btn_clock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
            Matrix mat=img.getImageMatrix();
            mMatrix.set(mat);
            mMatrix.setRotate(90);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), mMatrix, false);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });


    btn_antiClock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_AnticlockWise);
    btn_antiClock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
            Matrix mat=img.getImageMatrix();
            mMatrix.set(mat);
            mMatrix.setRotate(-90);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), mMatrix, false);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin answer**

use:

```
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:VERSION'
```

Get newest release here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/exifinterface

Function:

```
private fun adjustRotation(file: File): Bitmap{
    lateinit var rotatedBitmap: Bitmap
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
    val exifInterface = ExifInterface(file)
    val orientation: Int = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)

    fun rotateBitmap(source: Bitmap, angle: Int): Bitmap{
        val matrix = Matrix()
        matrix.postRotate(angle.toFloat())
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.width, source.height, matrix, true)
    }

    when (orientation){
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 ->
            rotatedBitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 ->
            rotatedBitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, 180)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 ->
            rotatedBitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, 270)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL ->
            rotatedBitmap = bitmap
        else -> rotatedBitmap = bitmap
    }
    return rotatedBitmap
}
```